# A Close formula.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, power-series, exponential-function

It is well known that $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{x^k}{k!}=\exp(x)$. My question is there an analogue of it for the sum $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k!}}$.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: [WolframAlpha isn't even trying for $x=1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(k%3D0)%5Einfty+1%2Fsqrt(k!)).

Comment: But there is a known name for $\sum\frac{x^k}{(k!)^2}$

Comment: For $\sum\frac{x^k}{(k!)^2}$ we have $\sum\frac{x^k}{(k!)^2}=BesselI(0,2\sqrt{x})$